# How can I copy the rule for a Dynamic Content box (created in ET content templates) into my HTML for an HTML paste email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, dynamic

Should be pretty simple.

I set up two different content boxes in ET with 2 different versions of a section of my email. I then created a Dynamic Content rule on when to use either one, using ET's content boxes.

Now I want to go back to my HTML email, replace that variable section WITH the Dynamic Content rule, so that I can then paste my email as HTML and send, retaining the Dynamic Content rules within the HTML so that it will send using the Dynamic Content rules.

This is not a triggered send; it's a manual triggered send.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you will need to use AMPscript to set your rules, and select the correct content area. For example:

```
%%[
  SET @condition = "true"
  IF @condition == "true" THEN
     Output(ContentAreaByName("my contents\A"))
  ELSE
    Output(ContentAreaByName("my contents\B"))
  ENDIF
]%%
```

When the `condition` is `true`, content area A will display. If `condition` is `false`, content area B will display.

The dynamic content areas are intended for templated content areas, and drag and drop functionality.  Calling `ContentAreaByName()` will show the reference ID's in the dynamic content area, but not the actual content as you would expect.